# Starting an online buiness as a minor

Tags: business, minor

Just start out, this is the closest to right area to post about a question like this I could find. Sorry if this is misplaced.

Anyways, I am looking to start a web design business as a minor ( I am very confident in my web design abilities..) As far as files and actual hosting issues are I am fine. As far as taxes come in, I am also fine as my parents are willing to help me out with where to start on filing them and such. (I have great parents.)
My issue comes in where In what I need to get done to start. Do I have to file for any sort of business classification or can I just get my site hosted and file the taxes if people purchase anything? Are there any legal disclaimers I should post? Also, as a note this is planned to be a solely operated business, owned and staffed by only me. (I believe that makes it a whole lot easier.)

Comment: I think you need to add your country and your exact age, because laws about business competence of minors vary from country to country.

Comment: "I have great parents. They're the very best, ask anyone, they would agree. Try calling Sean Hannity, he'll tell you."

Answer (score 1):

The major issue that you will face is that as a minor you are legally incompetent (sorry, not my choice of word) to contract. What that means is that any contract you enter is only binding on the other party (assuming they are an adult) - you can end it at any time. Consequently, your clients and suppliers may be reluctant to deal with you given that you can walk away from the deal anytime you want to.

As for the administrative matters involved in starting a business, they depend entirely on where your business is located and where it operates (which may be worldwide for a web based business): and you haven't told us where that is. Search your state or national government's web sites for "starting a business"

If you enter the world of business you can be sued and, unless you are incorporated, everything you own is at risk. You can take out professional indemnity insurance against this eventuality, however, premiums (in Australia) start from $5,000 per annum so you will need to factor these (and other) costs into what you charge your clients.